# read strings file in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

I'm trying to read a .strings file on mac with ruby 1.8.7. Below is the irb output. As you can see, `line` is a comment string that starts with `/*`. But when I do the `start_with` command, it returns false when I expected it to return true. I suspect is all the `\000` that is messing up the string compare.

So what can I do to remove the `\000`?

```
f = File.open("en.lproj/Localizable.strings")
#<File:en.lproj/Localizable.strings>

line = f.readline
"/\000*\000 \000T\000h\000i\000s\000 \000i\000s\000 \000a\000 \000s\000t\000r\000i\000n\000g\000 \000c\000o\000m\000m\000e\000n\000t\000 \000*\000/\000\r\000\n"

puts line
/* This is a string comment */

line.start_with?("/* ")
false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, try the obvious:

```
line.start_with?("/\000*\000 ")
```

The nul bytes, `"\000"`, don't have any visual representation so you don't see them when you `puts line` but you'll probably see them if you pipe your script's output through `cat -v`:

```
/^@*^@ ^@T^@h^@i^@s^@ ^@i^@s^@ ^@a^@ ^@s^@t^@r^@i^@n^@g^@ ^@c^@o^@m^@m^@e^@n^@t^@ ^@*^@/^@^M^@
```

The `^@` is how `cat -v` represents a zero byte.

**UPDATE:** If you want to remove the zero bytes then use [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001199) or [`tr!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001204):

```
line.tr!("\000", '')
```

I'm not sure about the format of a `.strings` file so you should figure that out and figure out the string encoding in particular. It looks like it might be UTF-16 but maybe not; if it is a standard non-ASCII encoding then you'll want to use [`iconv`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/index.html) to properly sort out the encoding.

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right. I decided to rephrase my question because in the end I'm interested in the string without null byte.